# Address for long stay visa in France

Tags: visa, france

My family and I are planning on heading to France for 6 months to travel. We are applying for a long stay D visa to allow us longer than the 90 day regular Schengen visa.

The application requires an address in France. We are planning to travel throughout France, staying in many different places, and will not have our accomodations pre-booked. We are not sure what to put in the address field.

There is no way to contact the French embassy in Canada (we are Canadians) and the embassy has contracted out all visa services to a company based in Mumbai called VFS. (I kid you not). We called VFS but they advised they will not answer any questions about filling in the form unless you pay a 'fee' to have someone assist you.

Can anyone help with our address problem? It appears the long stay visa is for residing at one address and travelling as a tourist throughout the country is not allowed on the long stay visa.